# I can't watch movies online with my Firefox

Tags: windows-7

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and I cannot watch movies online with my Firefox. I have tried installing Flash player for Windows, but it won't start installing.

Comment: How do you use **Windows** Firefox on Ubuntu?

Comment: windows firefox? Why? Why you don't use just [Firefox](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/firefox/)? It should be installed by default in Ubuntu. ...And *flash player for windows*? Why? There is [Adobe Flash plugin](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/flashplugin-installer/) - installer for the Adobe Flash plugin for Mozilla.

Answer (score 1):

First,I don't understand **Windows** Firefox in Ubuntu. So, I make an assumption that you are running Firefox which came **preinstalled** with Ubuntu. I suggest that you download the [**Adobe Flash plugin**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/flashplugin-installer/) from the Ubuntu Software Center:

[image: Install Adobe Flash plugin]

**Note that this is the last official version you will get.**
You can also try [Gnash](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/browser-plugin-gnash/), if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Well your first problem is attempting to use a windows application in Ubuntu.

The Adobe Flash Plugin can be installed for firefox from the Ubuntu Software Center. The major issue with Adobe's flash player is that it will never receive another update for linux.

Otherwise I'd recommend installing Google Chrome as Adobe Flash Player comes pre-bundled with the browser.